# Recreate Database when ASP.NET Core API server starts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am making an API with **ASP.NET Core**, **Entity Framework Core** and **SQL Server**.

I want to drop and recreate the Database when the Api server launches.
I tried adding these lines of code in the dbContext constructor :

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<Entretien> Entretiens { get; set; }
}
```

But then the Database is dropped and recreated at each request on the API (and not at server launch).

So my question is, where do I need to put these two lines so they re executed only when the server is launching ?

Comment: you should not call `EnsureCreated` if you're already calling `Migrate`

Comment: You might be better using an In Memory database if this is for testing/development - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/

Comment: Yes i made a mistake, I wanted to say I use `EnsureDeleted()` first, then I tested with both `EnsureCreated()` and `Migrate()` after.

Comment: Do not call `EnsureDeleted` if you don't want to delete your database...

Comment: But I want to delete it. The point is to have a fresh new Database at each launch. I used to code with EF 6, and I was doing `Database.SetInitializer<DBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DBContext>());` to accomplish that.

Comment: You'd be much better off doing this in another way, like a step in your release pipeline or something. Dropping and creating the database in the application requires that the database user the application uses is an admin, and that's a *very* bad idea from a security standpoint. Any DB user for a web application should have the most limited privileges possible - maybe even just `SELECT`, but certainly not more than `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` (and you should think twice on that one as well).

Comment: I am still in designing step, and for the moment my API and database are only in local (localhost). I am testing different sorts of things on my database architecture and my client. Once my ideas about the API design will be clearer, i will follow the common practices for database security

Comment: That kind of just makes it even more senseless, actually. Adding code explicitly just for development, means that you then need to remove that code before you go live. It also is just frankly more complicated than just running something like `dotnet ef database drop` and then `dotnet ef database update`, when you want. Then, you can actually keep some dev data around if you need to, until you actually *need* to drop and create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a web host method extension and call it before start you app

**WebHostExtensions.cs**

```
public static class WebHostExtensions{
   public static IWebHost InitDataBase(this IWebHost host){
       using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
       {
           var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
           dbContext = services.GetService<YourDbContext>();
           // your code here
       }
   }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().InitDataBase().Run();
}
```